# How to try a Wordpress or Joomla extension/component for free?

Tags: plugins, wordpress, joomla

I'm new to CMS, and couldn't install a plugin/component using free Wordpress/Joomla accounts. What's the best and easiest way to try such plugins/components?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish what you are wanting is to install a WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) stack... assuming you are running Windows here.  If you are running Linux, look at installing LAMP (Linux.... you get the idea).

My Personal favourite WAMP Stack is EasyPHP and it can be [downloaded from here](http://www.easyphp.org/easyphp-webserver.php)

I can personally vouch that I have run Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla and custom coded sites here while developing addons and modules as a contractor.

Once installed, you will get a system tray icon which offers you access to places like phpmyadmin.  using phpmyadmin, you can create a new database, new database user and then grant the mysql user rights to the database.

Once done, its as simple as copying the installer files for your chosen CMS to your web servers root folder and go through the install the same as any other website.

Hope this helps.